# Function of Functions - pass variable between scopes - powershell

Tags: powershell, function, variables, scope

I am looking to create a some functions that create a result in a variable within the scope of a function and then pass that variable from one function to another function.  as a simplified example, say I wanted the test1 function to combine two strings and then have another function that can take an action on that combined string.  How would I do that?  I know I could always put the function call of test two within the function of test1 but, that could get messing and confusing if I had several functions I needed to do that with.  Is there a way to get that variable to be saved outside the scope of test1 function so test 2 can use it when called from a third function?  My thoughts are that I need to do several different tasks that will be handled by different functions and then have a main function (funcOfFuncs in this example) that would call the functions when needed based on different criteria.  Would I need a global variable or is there a way to pass that $t1combine back out of test one to be used later?  I tried utilizing return but that did not work.

```
$test1a = "foo"
$test1b = "bar"


function test1 {
    param (
    $test1a, 
    $test1b
    )
    $t1combine = $test1a + $test1b
    Write-host "We are in test func 1"
    write-host $test1a " ... " $test1b
    Write-host $t1combine
}

function test2 {
    param ($t1combine)
    write-host "Inside test 2 func....." $t1combine
}


function funcOfFuncs{

test1 $test1a $test1b
test2 $t1combine
}

funcofFuncs
```

I know the above will not work as $t1combine is in the test1 function scope.  I attempted making a separate variable outside of all functions and setting equal to the function ($x = test1) but that did not work.  I tried adding return $t1combine to the test1 function but that did not work for making the $t1combine available outside the test1 function.  Any assistance that can be provided would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your use of `Write-Host` in your examples, the output from this cmdlet goes to the [Information Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.3#information-stream) and serves for informational purposes primarily, if you want your function to output a value that can be captured without the need for *redirection*, then just remove it.

> Would I need a global variable or is there a way to pass that `$t1combine` back out of test one to be used later?

No, there is no need to and it provides a bad UX, have your function return a value, store that value in a variable and then pass that value as argument to whatever other function might need it

```
function test1 {
    param ($test1a, $test1b)

    Write-host "We are in $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
    $test1a + $test1b # <= this is the output that can be captured from your func
}
function test2 {
    param ($t1combine)

    Write-host "We are in $($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name)"
    Write-host "Received value [$t1combine]"
}

$result = test1 "foo" "bar"
test2 $result
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a bit more reading up on how Functions work (e.g. [PowerShell 101 Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions)), as it will help you complete what you are trying to do.

Basically you don't have to resort to global variables. You are missing 2 things from your example. Instead of `Write-Host` which writes out to the screen, you use `Write-Output` to "return" values back from the function. And second, you need to take the return value and store it in a variable (e.g. `$t1combine`).

Here is the example code:

```
$test1a = "foo"
$test1b = "bar"

function test1 {
    param (
    $test1a, 
    $test1b
    )
    $t1combine = $test1a + $test1b
    Write-host "We are in test func 1"
    write-host $test1a " ... " $test1b
    Write-Output $t1combine
}

function test2 {
    param ($t1combine)
    write-host "Inside test 2 func....." $t1combine
}


function funcOfFuncs{

$t1combine = test1 $test1a $test1b
test2 $t1combine
}

funcofFuncs
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're wanting to save the output of `test1()` into a variable and then pass the var to `test2()`. If that's the case, then you're close. You'll want to remove the `Write-Host` at the end of `test1()` so you return `$t1combine` and then change `funcOfFuncs()` to the following

```
function funcOfFuncs{
    $test1Output = test1 $test1a $test1b
    $test2Output = test2 $test1Output
    Write-Host $test2Output
}
```